# C++ templates which infer class members

Tags: c++, class, templates, declaration, member

I know that I can use templates to assume that certain classes used by the template have certain member variables;  however, I was wondering if there was a way to explicitly declare that the template class has to have a certain member variable or function?

I am talking about something like this example:

```
template <typename T>
class Assume
{
    int value;
    Assume(T* object) : value(T->AssumedMember) {};
};


class A
{
    int AssumedMember;
    A(int val) : AssumedMember(val) {};
};


int main()
{
    A* a = new A(5);
    Assume<A> assumer(a);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that, at least with the compiler used in MSVC++, something similar to this example should compile without a problem;

I was merely wondering if there was a way to declare that, for the template or class's use, that T, from typename T, has a member variable AssumedMember.  As of now, the only way to really understand that Assume will only work if used with a class that has the right required members (variables, functions, or operators), one would either have to compile and look at the given compiler error, or read through the entire template yourself to determine if anything extra is being used that has not been defined yet.

(also, on an unrelated note, does anyone know of a way to declare a whole block of declarations as being a template?  As if using something like:
  `template <typename T> { /*class... member definitions, etc..*/ }`
to declare a whole block of definitions to use the same template?)

Comment: In C++11 you can use a member-existence trait check like `has_begin_end` in the [C++ pretty printer](https://raw.github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint/master/prettyprint.hpp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to declare a templates requirements other than in the template's definition. You can use static_asserts, for example, to put those requirements right up front in the definition and give better error messages.

To declare several template functions at once you could use a template class with static member functions:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo {
    static int bar(T t);
    static T baz();
};

Foo<int>::bar(1);
auto s = Foo<std::string>::baz();
```

But there's no general purpose way of doing this for any kind of template declaration, and I don't think this saves you much of anything.

---

#### Example of custom type traits for use with static_asserts

I use some C++11 stuff, but it can be done in C++98 as well

```
#include <type_traits>

// the custom type traits
template<typename T> struct exists : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct has_value_type {
    template<typename U>
    static typename std::enable_if<exists<typename U::value_type>::value,char>::type
    Test(int);

    template<typename U> static int Test(...);
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char);
};

template<typename T>
struct has_member_i {
    template<typename U>
    static typename std::enable_if<0!=sizeof(&U::i),char>::type Test(int);
    template<typename U> static int Test(...);
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof(Test<T>(0)) == sizeof(char);
};

// your template for which you want to declare requirements
template<typename T>
void test(T t) {
    static_assert(has_value_type<T>::value, "value_type must be a member type alias of T");
    static_assert(has_member_i<T>::value, "i must be a member variable of T");
}

// one type that meets the requirements and one that doesn't
struct Foo {
    typedef int value_type;
    int i;
};

struct Bar {};

int main() {
    test(Foo());
    test(Bar());
}
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to say static_assert(X is member of Y, "X needs to be a member of Y!"); ?  This sounds like a good way to handle it, until the next version of C++ or something.

Comment: I've never before seen templates being used in such interesting, and useful, manners.  Thank you very much!

Comment: The more powerful uses of templates are referred to as 'template meta-programming' if you're interested. You can even use them to perform turning complete computation at compile time.

Comment: @bames52 Thank you;  All resources I've really read on templates have not come anywhere close to things as complex as this;  however, at the time, I did not know of the term "template meta-programming", either.  Learn something new every day!

Comment: I recently tried this code, and I'm getting a compilation problem (other than the expected ones); it claims an illegal sizeof operator when attempting to get the size of Test<T>(0), in has_member_i  (but not in has_value_type!)

Any ideas about this? =/

Comment: Nevermind; I managed to solve the issue by changing sizeof(&U::i) to sizeof(U().i)

Thank you!

Comment: @StefanZuefeldt The expression where I use `0!=sizeof(&U::i)` needs to be something that is well formed and evaluates to true whenever the type matches whatever requirement you're checking (and is otherwise ill-formed or evaluates to false). So replacing `&U::i` with `U().i` is fine except that `U()` requires the type to be default constructible. C++11 provides `declval` for this sort of thing: `std::declval<U>().i`

Answer (score 2):

The Standard committee has been working on this feature, which is called "concepts". However, it didn't make it into C++11.

There are two compilers that have it working (with various capabilities), however.  Take a look at [ConceptGCC](http://www.generic-programming.org/software/ConceptGCC/) or [ConceptClang](http://www.generic-programming.org/software/ConceptClang/).

Comment: Well, glad this idea is at least being looked into/worked on, thanks for the info!

Comment: Boost provides a library to "emulate" concepts : http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm  but I've never used it